# Android: Shape an ImageView

Tags: java, android, eclipse, mask

I'm having some troubles in developing an android app. I hope you can help me out ;)

This is what I want to achieve:
I want to program a watch  and therefore I created a bitmap with a clockhand on it. Then I used an Imageview to display this bitmap and set an animation for this Imageview to rotate it.

My problem is:
Now I want to give the ImageView different shapes (for example the shape of a hexagon). I tried all sorts of custom ImageViews and Custom Layouts, edited my bitmap with the codes canvas and paint,... but with all these codes there is one main issue:
I can only shape the Imageview and so the "shape" rotates as well as the bitmap (because of the rotate animation of the ImageView). But I want something like putting an alpha mask over the ImageView so that the Bitmap with the clockhand can rotate, but the shape stays as it is.

After a lot of research on the internet and many hours of testing codes, I thought about asking the community.

I'm looking forward to any constructive suggestion.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is one possibility, but I'm not sure about the performance. Instead of rotating the ImageView itself, use a transformation matrix to rotate the Bitmap.

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(deg);
mImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
mImageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

This should rotate only the *content* itself, and not the view.

(Note that if you were already using `scaleType`, you will need to change this matrix slightly, e.g. using `setRectToRect()` before `postRotate()`).